# PHPmyadmin Login without a password is forbidden by configuration even when entering password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Basically it is all in title. I did a clean install of CentOS7.2 (needed CentOS7 for running ARK). I made a LAMP server and it is working with tests, and then I installed PHPmyadmin. Whenever I try to log in on the site I get error Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword) even when I enter the password in the field when trying root. I can even try to enter in some junk user and pass and it gives me Cannot log in to the MySQL server. Just when I try to enter with root and pass. Anyone have any tips on where it may have gone wrong? I can get in perfectly fine when I make this on a CentOS6.6 but I need the updated gblibc and gcc that come in 7 (I could try to attempt a fix for 6.6 if I have to).

Comment: I also did add allow root remote login of mysql, no dice.

Comment: Are you able to connect from the command line client? Something like `mysql -u root -p` should be close.